# Trying to solve a simple dice game probability using a transition matrix

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I play the following game: "I roll 2 dices, I win if the sum of the 2 dices is 5, I lose if the sum is 7, otherwise I roll them again" What is my probability of winning?

It can be easily shown the probability is 0.4. 
However, I thought, such game is an example of a Markov chain and I also tried to solve it as such. Hence I defined 3 states: **W**in, **L**oss, **C**ontinue, the following transition matrix $T$:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 4/36  \\
    0 & 1 & 6/36  \\
    0 & 0 & 26/36 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

and the following intial vector $X_{0}$:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I see that when **n** increase,  $T^n.X_{0}$ converges as I expected to 
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0.4  \\
    0.6  \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

However, when I tried to get the long-term stable states by looking at the eigenvalues, eigenvectors I did not find what I was looking for, i.e. I was expecting eigen value of 1 and eigen vector (0.4, 0.6, 0)

Can someone tell me whether or not this is a Markov Chain example. If it is, why I cannot find the long term solution by looking at the eigen values and vectors ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For there to be a unique stationary distribution, the Markov chain must be both irreducible and aperiodic. It fails the first requirement because of the two absorbing states: it’s not possible to get to any other state from them, let alone to *every* other state.

In terms of eigenvectors of the transition matrix, you should have found that the eigenspace of $1$ is two-dimensional, so even if you consider only eigenvectors with entries in $[0,1]$ that sum to $1$, there’s an infinite number of them.

You can, however, analyze it using standard techniques for [absorbing Markov chains](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#). For this process, the fundamental matrix $N$ is just the scalar $1/(1-26/36)=18/5$, and the absorption probabilities are $\frac{18}5\left(\frac19,\frac16\right)=\left(\frac25,\frac35\right)$, which agrees with your direct computation.

Comment: thank you for the detailed and so informative answer!